# c++11 (MSVS2012) regex looking for file names in multiple line std::string

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I have been trying to search for a clear answer on this one, but not been able to find it.

So lets say I have the string (where \n could be \r\n - I want to handle both - not sure if that is relevant or not)

```
"4345t435\ng54t a_file_123.xml rk\ngreg a_file_j34.xml fger 43t54"
```

Then I want to get matches:

- a_file_123.xml
- a_file_j34.xml

Here is my test code:

```
const str::string s = "4345t435\ng54t a_file_123.xml rk\ngreg a_file_j34.xml fger 43t54";

std::smatch matches;
if (std::regex_search(s, matches, std::regex("a_file_(.*)\\.xml")))
{
    std::cout << "total: " << matches.size() << std::endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "match: " << matches[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
total: 2
match: a_file_123.xml
match: 123
```

I don't quite understand why match 2 is just "123"...

Comment: If you want to match multiple strings, you need to use the regex iterator, not just `regex_search`. And it seems you are using `a_file_(.*).xml` regex, right?

Comment: oops - sorry that is meant to be `a_file_(.*)\\.xml` - typeo

Comment: Yeah, I guessed it by your results. Good, so you need to use 1) regex iterator and 2) a lazy `.*?` dot matching pattern or `[^.]*?` to prevent matching `.`s before `.xml`. And you only have 1 match, not 2. What you printed was two *group* values, Group 0 (the whole match) and Group 1 (the capturing group value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have one match, not two, as the `regex_search` method returns a single match. What you printed is two *group* values, Group 0 (the whole match, `a_file_123.xml` here) and Group 1 (the capturing group value, here, `123` that is a substring *captured* with a capturing group you defined as `(.*)` in the pattern).

If you want to match multiple strings, you need to use the regex iterator, not just a `regex_search` that only returns the first match.

Besides, `.*` is too greedy and will return weird results if you have more than 1 match on the same line. It seems you want to match letter or digits, so `.*` can be replaced with `\w+`. Well, if there can really be anything, just use `.*?`.

Use

```
const std::string s = "4345t435\ng54t a_file_123.xml rk\ngreg a_file_j34.xml fger 43t54";
const std::regex rx("a_file_\\w+\\.xml");
std::vector<std::string> results(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), rx),
                           std::sregex_token_iterator());

std::cout << "Number of matches: " << results.size() << std::endl;
for (auto result : results)
{
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/NP8HTR) yielding

```
Number of matches: 2
a_file_123.xml
a_file_j34.xml
```

**Notes on regex**

- `a_file_` - a literal substring
- `\\w+` - 1+ word chars (letters, digits, `_`) (note you may use `[^.]*?` here instead of `\\w+` if you want to match any char, 0 or more repetitions, as few as possible, up to the first `.xml`)
- `\\.` - a dot (if you do not escape it, it will match any char except line break chars)
- `xml` - a literal substring.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DIB7kT/1/)

Comment: That's probably the coolest answer I have seen - its got a demo!, thanks v much : )

Comment: Would it be cool to use the regex ([\w_\d]+.xml) for generic xml file names?

Comment: @Jorge.V Well, it is difficult to say because Linux and Windows file name specs differ (no idea about Mac OS). Probably you may just use `.*?`. Note that `[\w_\d]` = `\w`. If you can describe the context around the expected matches, it would be best, together with the lazy dot (`.*?`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. I'm trying to learn regex atm :) Very cool answer btw.